# bibtex does not show all the entries of @inCollection

Tags: bibtex

Using `bibtex`The url does not appear in the references using the following @inCollection

```
@InCollection{simplicity,
author       =  {Baker, Alan},
title        =  {Simplicity},
booktitle    =  {The Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy},
editor       =  {Edward N. Zalta},
howpublished =  {\url{http://plato.stanford.edu/archives/fall2013/entries/simplicity/}},
year         =  {2013},
edition      =  {Fall 2013},
```

}

and it appears as: 
Alan Baker. Simplicity. In Edward N. Zalta, editor, The Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy. Fall 2013 edition, 2013.

Comment: The `howpublished` field is not a standard field for the `@incollection` type; in fact I think it is only used for the @misc type. Use the `url` field and use a bibliography style that supports URLs. What you've given here isn't enough to completely diagnose your problem; ideally you should give a tiny complete compilable document that shows how you are creating your bibliography.

Answer (score 6):

It's important to keep in mind that it is not BibTeX *per se* but the bibliography style that determines which fields are shown (and how they're formatted) for a given entry. It looks like you're using the `plain` bibliography style -- or some close relative of `plain`. As @AlanMunn has already observed in a comment, `plain` is *not* programmed to do anything with a field named `howpublished` unless the entry type is `@misc`.

However, `plain` (and many other bibliography styles too) *are* programmed to do something with a field named `note` for entries of type `@incollection`. Thus, if you change the field name from `howpublished` to `note` *and* load the [url](http://ctan.org/pkg/url) package, you'll get this result:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@InCollection{simplicity,
author       =  {Baker, Alan},
title        =  {Simplicity},
booktitle    =  {The Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy},
editor       =  {Edward N. Zalta},
note         =  {\url{http://plato.stanford.edu/archives/fall2013/entries/simplicity/}},
year         =  {2013},
edition      =  {Fall 2013},
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{url}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

---

Alternatively, you could switch from `plain` to `plainnat`, load the [natbib](http://ctan.org/pkg/natbib) package (as well as the `url` package, as above), change the field name to `url`, and remove the `\url` wrapper from the field's contents to get this look:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@InCollection{simplicity,
author       =  {Baker, Alan},
title        =  {Simplicity},
booktitle    =  {The Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy},
editor       =  {Edward N. Zalta},
url          =  {http://plato.stanford.edu/archives/fall2013/entries/simplicity/},
year         =  {2013},
edition      =  {Fall 2013},
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

---

Incidentally, in both examples given above, the URL string will be made into a hyperlink to the corresponding web page if you load `hyperref` instead of (or in addition to) `url`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked perfectly fine. I use `unsrt` package and I guess it wont work with the `plainnat`. but other than that, I used `hyperref` and changed `howpublished` to note and everything is perfectly fine.

Comment: @Ramin - Glad that the first solution works for you. Regarding the second solution: You could use `unsrtnat`. The styles `plain` and `unsrt` are close siblings, as are `plainnat` and `unsrtnat`.