# Having references in the same latex file

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies, amsrefs

Is there a way to have references in the same latex file (i.e. instead of having the references in a separate .bib file)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You could, for example, use the `filecontents` package to provide the bibliographic entries in the preamble of your document. For a practical example of this approach, see the posting http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/185067/5001.

Comment: See also [How to write a MWEB (Minimal working example with Bibliography)?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)

Answer (score 32):

Yes and no.

You can create your own bibliography *manually*:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{xx}
  \bibitem{abc}
  \textsc{Author}, \textit{Title}, ...

  ...

\end{thebibliography}
```

However, this lacks consistency through automation as well as ease-of-maintenance.

A far better alternative to handling a bibliography "within the same file" would be to embed it via the aid of the`filecontents` or `filecontents*` environment (with the `overwrite` option to accommodate perpetual changes). This way you can manage your bibliography within the main TeX file, while it is actually always written out to file for use in the expected way.

Here is [an example](//tex.stackexchange.com/a/88382/5764):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{general.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{general.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The file `general.bib` is overwritten with every compilation, allowing you to add/remove bibliography entries as you please. Every change, however, should still be accompanied with the appropriate BibTeX engine ([`biber`](//biblatex-biber.sourceforge.net/) in the above case).

Comment: this code needs a biblatex.sty file, how to do that?

Comment: @user3741635 you need to install biblatex.  On miktex and texlive there are package installers to do this for you.

Comment: @user3741635: You can follow the direction in [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://goo.gl/CqWB1) to install packages. If you're talking about the general use of a bibliography and how to obtain/display it in your document, then that's a different question. That requires a compilation sequence (pdf)LaTeX > BibTeX/Biber > (pdf)LaTeX (and possibly one more (pdf)LaTeX).

Comment: is it possible to add references to this file 

\documentclass{article}



\title{Hello}
\author{My Name}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
A1
\section{Literature Review}
A2

\section{Conclusion}
A2


\end{document}

Comment: @user3741635: Yes.

Comment: @Werner I am sorry, but when do I need to use the starred version of  `filecontents`?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou: The `filecontents` environment adds a specific 4-line commented header to the output file (see page 2 of the [`filecontents` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/filecontents/filecontents.pdf)). `filecontents*` does not add this header. You'd use `filecontents*` when eventual reading may have comments (via `%`) interpreted; this is typically the case when you would read in via (say) `\lstinputlisting`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! By the way, I hope there could be better ways which does not require compiling multiple times.

Comment: @zyy: You need need to compile multiple times with every *change* in the bibliography. Once there aren't changes, a single compilation should suffice. The same goes for references.

Answer (score 13):

In case this is the request of a publisher who wants only one file compiling with standard packages only, the classical way of doing this is:

1. Use bibtex when preparing your manuscript, say `manuscript.tex`.
2. Before sending to the publisher, make a copy your manuscript `.tex` file, say to `submitted_version.tex`, edit that copy and replace the lines calling Bibtex by the contents of the `manuscript.bbl` file.

Send that file `submitted_version.tex` to the publisher.

Comment: Though this is common, all cases I've come across for this require `bibtex` not `biblatex` - be warned :)

Answer (score 3):

In addition, you may use the [amsrefs](http://www.ams.org/publications/authors/tex/amsrefs)-package.

According to the documentation, there are three ways of using the package:

1. Enter bibliography items directly in your LaTeX-document using the
   `biblist`-environment and the `\bib`-command.
2. Import items from an external `.ltb`-ﬁle.
3. Import items from a `.bib` ﬁle using BibTeX and the special bibliography
   styles distributed with the `amsrefs`-package

Item 1 is the method you are asking for. The amsrefs-package is included in TeX-distributions.

Comment: An example for the how to use the syntax would be really nice

Comment: @lucidbrot The [package documentation](https://ctan.asis.ai/macros/latex/contrib/amsrefs/amsrdoc.pdf) offers simple examples for each of the three methods at the beginning itself. You may glance through it to gather an idea of what it's like.